# How to show columns in row on firebird2.5?

Tags: sql, pivot, firebird, firebird2.5

I have one table and I need to do sql query which convert rows on columns. My table looks like this:

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    Id |IdR |DateFrom    |DateTo      |NameOfHappening |Amount

    293|264 |01.06.2019  |30.06.2019  |Disease 1       |2836.80
    369|600 |01.07.2019  |07.07.2019  |Disease 1       |661.92
    646|631 |01.08.2019  |11.08.2019  |Disease 1       |876.59
    647|631 |12.08.2019  |21.08.2019  |Disease 2       |796.90
    840|703 |30.09.2019  |30.09.2019  |Disease 1       |90.75
    971|718 |31.05.2019  |31.05.2019  |Disease 1       |0.00
```

I wrote query which show date but I have problem with other columns. My SQL query looks like this:

```
select
a.IDR,
(select max(op.DATE_FROM) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR) as DATE_FROM_HP1,
(select max(op.DATE_TO) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR) as DATE_TO_HP1,
(select max(op.DATE_FROM) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR group by op.DATE_FROM order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 2 to 2) as DATE_FROM_HP2,
(select max(op.DATE_TO) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR group by op.DATE_FROM order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 2 to 2) as DATE_TO_HP2,
(select max(op.DATE_FROM) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR group by op.DATE_FROM order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 3 to 3) as DATE_FROM_HP3,
(select max(op.DATE_TO) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR group by op.DATE_FROM order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 3 to 3) as DATE_TO_HP3
from HAPP_TABLE a
group by a.IDR
```

To this column date I need to connect other data from column NameOfHappening and Amount in one row group by IDR column. But data from this two column I can't get like date query date. I have to select this column to row that corresponding to dates. I want to get something like this:

```
IdR  DATE_FROM_HP1  DATE_TO_HP1   DATE_FROM_HP2  DATE_TO_HP2

264 |01.06.2019    |30.06.2019    |Disease 1|null           |null       |null
600 |01.07.2019    |07.07.2019    |Disease 1|null           |null       |null
631 |12.08.2019    |21.08.2019    |Disease 2|01.08.2019     |11.08.2019 |Disease 1
703 |30.09.2019    |30.09.2019    |Disease 1|null           |null       |null
718 |31.05.2019    |31.05.2019    |Disease 1|null           |null       |null
```

Please help me with this problem because I try a few solution and each ended with a multiple row selection message.

Comment: You're attempting to select the first, second or third row of a query that only has a single row.

Comment: Yes I know that, I want to get three entries with dates if of course they are exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery to get the "previous" row and then join back:

```
select h.*, hprev.*  -- select whatever columns you want
from (select h.*,
             (select max(h2.date)
              from happ_table h2
              where h2.idr = h.idr and
                    h2.date_from < h.date_from
             ) as prev_date_from
      from happ_table h
     ) h left join
     happ_table hprev
     on hprev.idr = h.idr and
        hprev.date_from = h.prev_date_from;
```

Notes:

- In Firebird 3+, this is much simpler with `lag()`.
- I'm not sure if the dates are unique.  Perhaps the first column is the right column for specifying the "previous" row.

Comment: Which table is t2? I can`t find it on this query?

Comment: Ok, but when I run this query I get two records with two IdR=631. I need to group this on one record. Do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

A query like `select max(op.DATE_FROM) from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR` only has one row, so the addition of the `rows 2 to 2` or `rows 3 to 3` is not going to produce values.

In addition, your usage of `max` will produce values that don't necessarily belong together, so it might produce the wrong result

You can change your existing query by removing the use of `max`, applying a consistent order by and fetching specific rows, eg:

```sql
select
a.IDR,
(select op.DATE_FROM from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR order by op.DATE_FROM rows 1) as DATE_FROM_HP1,
(select op.DATE_TO from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR order by op.DATE_FROM rows 1) as DATE_TO_HP1,
(select op.DATE_FROM from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 2 to 2) as DATE_FROM_HP2,
(select op.DATE_TO from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 2 to 2) as DATE_TO_HP2,
(select op.DATE_FROM from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 3 to 3) as DATE_FROM_HP3,
(select op.DATE_TO from HAPP_TABLE op where op.IDR=a.IDR order by op.DATE_FROM desc rows 3 to 3) as DATE_TO_HP3
from HAPP_TABLE a
group by a.IDR
```

However, the solution suggested by Gordon is probably better.